# existence of solutions to $Ax=b$ over the positive integers

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am interested in literature concerning whether a solution to the system $Ax=b$ exists when $A \in \mathbb{N_+}^{n\times n}$ and $x,b\in \mathbb{N_+}$. Here $\mathbb{N}_+$ denotes the positive integers $1,2,3,\dots$. Theorems over $\mathbb{Z}$ are also useful. I understand this is a nontrivial task since $\mathbb{N}_+$ isn't even a field.

Comment: There is a lot of literature, called "Linear Diophantine Equations". See for example [here](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~wgilbert/Research/GilbertPathria.pdf), or search for it. For the same question see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078707/algorithm-for-finding-integer-solutions-to-a-system-of-linear-diophantine-equati?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks, @DietrichBurde To be precise I'm interested only in the existence of a solution to a linear diophantine equation, rather than explicit algorithms to compute such solutions. Still, this is great to know--I now have a name!

Comment: Also on existence of a solution you will find enough. See for example [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13398-011-0044-4), or search for it.